# How can I toggle between three predefined positions?

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to create an Emacs like `Ctrl-l` feature, similar to Vim's H, M and L. For those who don't now, these keys jump to top, middle, and bottom of the window. I already have something but I am missing the "if" part.

```
function! ToggleHML()
    let l:winheight = winheight('%')
    let l:top = 1
    let l:middle = l:winheight / 2
    let l:bottom = l:winheight
    if ...
endfunction
```

I think I have to create another variable to keep the state until the next function call, but I don't know how to.

Another thing I ended up thinking, exec a normal command inside the function. Something like:

```
:exec 'normal! H'
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
function! ToggleHML()
    if winline() < winheight('%') / 2
      normal M
    elseif winline() < winheight('%')
      normal L
    else
      normal H
    endif
endfunction
```

I removed the variables, since they aren't really necessary. This will always jump down unless it's already at the bottom, in which case it will jump up.

Comment: Not yet, it never jumps to the top.

Comment: The problem with `winheight('%')` only,  is that sometimes we have a file smaller than it, so in my soulution, yes I figured it out, I have an if clause to test if the `winheight('%')` is bigger than `line('$')`.

Answer (score 0):

After some sweat, I figured out one solution, not so easy as I thought. We have to discover if the file is larger or not than `winheight('%')`.

```
function! ToggleHML()
    set scrolloff=0
    let l:last_win_line = ( line('$') <= winheight('%') ? line('$')  : winheight('%')  )
    if winline() < l:last_win_line / 2
      normal M
    elseif winline() < l:last_win_line
      normal L
    else
      normal H
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <C-l> :call ToggleHML()<CR>
```

Reference: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Vim-General-f1139531.html 
were I figured ou how to get the last line number `line('$')`.

Comment: Special thanks to [vi.stackexchange.com/users/2920/djmcmayhem](DJMcMayhem) for his special interest and giving us the `winline() and winheight('%')` tips.